# correlationId dosn't exist in node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, middleware

I am trying to add correlationId using express-correlation-id. I am exactly following the page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-correlation-id. I've imported the express-correlation-id pkg and have found it in the package.json and node modules.

But when i tried to get req.correlationId(), it always said:

Property 'correlationId' dosn't exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.

I'm using TypeScript and Express, this is what the code looks like:

```
import correlator = require("express-correlation-id");
app.use(correlator());
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    req.correlationId();    // where the error occurs
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this package is written in js language, there are no type definition files for typescript, so you need to extend the `Express.Request` interface by yourself, add the `correlationId` method to the interface.

Package versions:

- `"typescript": "^3.9.7"`
- `"express-correlation-id": "^1.3.1",`
- `"express": "^4.17.1",`

E.g.

`server.ts`:

```js
import express from 'express';
import correlator = require('express-correlation-id');

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
      correlationId(): string;
    }
  }
}

const app = express();

app.use(correlator());
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  req.correlationId();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. If I extends the Request interface, do I need to implement correlationId() method by myself or just need to write as above? In the js npm package req.correlationId() is already handled in the middleware.

Comment: @TonyStark You don't need to implement it. It's implemented by the package. You just provide the types for typescript.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the property `correlationId` doesn't exist in the typing of `req`.

So, if you see the [typing of `req`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L219)  is:

```js
export interface Request<P = ParamsDictionary, ResBody = any, ReqBody = any, ReqQuery = ParsedQs> extends http.IncomingMessage, Express.Request {
```

So, you must create a new Request type with the new functions that you're going to use. For your case:

```
import express from "express";
import correlator = require("express-correlation-id");
import { ParamsDictionary, Request } from "express-serve-static-core";
import { ParsedQs } from "qs";

const app = express();

interface CustomReq<P = ParamsDictionary, ResBody = any, ReqBody = any, ReqQuery = ParsedQs> extends Request<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery> {
    // extended options
    correlationId: () => any;
}

app.use(correlator());
app.get('/', (req: CustomReq, res) => {
    req.correlationId(); // OK
});
```

As you see in the code above, my new `Request` is `CustomReq` and I use the new type for the `req`.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I have the same question as stated in the above answer. If I extends the Request interface, do I need to implement correlationId() method by myself or just need to write as above? In the js npm package req.correlationId() is already handled in the middleware.

Comment: @TonyStark you assume the method exists because when you do `app.use(correlator())` that adds the method inside `req`. You only need to change the type of `req` to say to the TS compiler "Hey, correlationId() exists and returns me an any (or whatever you expect)". TypeScript only checks the type, so in the interface, you can add "`lala: () => any`" and if you call `req.lala()` in the ts-build must be OK but when you execute the code will throw an error because `lala doesn't exist in req`.